# Xamarin forms removing whitespaces in run-time

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

we're building a cross-plataform app with xamarin forms in visual studio, and for iOS the app works great, but when i build it and run on my phone, or even emulator, the whitespaces, or just spaces, are being removed from my strings, using static resources or just strings itself in the xaml files, encoding is `utf-8` and i did check the strings.resx is all `xml:space="preserve"`
i've checked everything i could think, if someone could enlighten me on this one

like for example the space in the privacy policy string, when running on android it removes the space... it does not even matter if the string is put on the resources or the xaml page

thank you

edit : following some part of the code

The xaml page ex

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Driver.View.Register"
             xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Driver.Infra.Resources;assembly=Driver"
             xmlns:viewt="clr-namespace:Driver.ViewTemplate;assembly=Driver"
             Title="Faça seu Cadastro">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout 
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Padding="15">
                <ScrollView>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <!--<Image Source="logotipo.png"/>-->
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                            <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="80">
                                <viewt:CustomPicker
                                x:Name="PckDDI"
                                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                                Title="{x:Static resx:Strings.CountryCode}"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                <Label RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=PckDDI, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                                Text="{x:Static viewt:FontAwesome.faBars}"
                                TextColor="{x:StaticResource ColorPrimary}"
                                FontSize="Small"
                                FontFamily="FontAwesome"
                                HorizontalOptions="End"
                                Margin="0,12,10,0"
                                InputTransparent="True"/>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <viewt:CustomEntry
                            MaxLength="11"
                            Keyboard="Numeric"
                            Placeholder="{x:Static resx:Strings.PhoneEx}"
                            PlaceholderColor="LightGray"
                            HeightRequest="40"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            x:Name="TxtPhone"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <viewt:CustomEntry
                        MaxLength="50"
                        Keyboard="Default"
                        Placeholder="{x:Static resx:Strings.Name}"
                        PlaceholderColor="LightGray"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        x:Name="TxtName"/>
                        <viewt:CustomEntry
                        MaxLength="8"
                        Keyboard="Default"
                        Placeholder="{x:Static resx:Strings.Plate}"
                        PlaceholderColor="LightGray"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        x:Name="TxtPlate"/>
                        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <viewt:CustomPicker
                                x:Name="PckVehicleType"
                                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                                Title="{x:Static resx:Strings.VehicleType}"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                            <Label RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=PckVehicleType, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                                Text="{x:Static viewt:FontAwesome.faBars}"
                                TextColor="{x:StaticResource ColorPrimary}"
                                FontSize="Small"
                                FontFamily="FontAwesome"
                                HorizontalOptions="End"
                                Margin="0,12,10,0"
                                InputTransparent="True"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <viewt:CustomPicker
                                x:Name="PckBodyType"
                                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                                Title="{x:Static resx:Strings.TransportType}"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                            <Label RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=PckBodyType, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                                Text="{x:Static viewt:FontAwesome.faBars}"
                                TextColor="{x:StaticResource ColorPrimary}"
                                FontSize="Small"
                                FontFamily="FontAwesome"
                                HorizontalOptions="End"
                                Margin="0,12,10,0"
                                InputTransparent="True"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                            <Switch 
                        x:Name="SwtPrivacyPolicy"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        IsToggled="True"/>
                            <Label 
                            Text="{x:Static resx:Strings.PrivacyPolicyText}"
                            TextColor="Black"
                            FontSize="Micro">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Tapped="LabelPrivacyPolicy_Tapped"
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Switch
                            x:Name="SwtReceivePrepaidCard"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            IsToggled="False"/>
                            <Label
                            Text="{x:Static resx:Strings.PrePaidCardText}"
                            TextColor="Black"
                            FontSize="Micro">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Tapped="LabelReceivePrepaidCard_Tapped"
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                    <viewt:CustomButton
                    x:Name="ButtonRegister"
                    Text="{x:Static resx:Strings.Register}"
                    TextColor="White"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <viewt:LoadingView
                x:Name="LoadingIndicator"
                IsVisible="false"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

An example of the resource strings

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="PrivacyPolicyText" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Read and Accept the TERMS AND CONDITIONS about the use of the plataform and privacy policy</value>
  </data>
```

Comment: this is too vague, maybe post the corresponding components, e.g. the code of the resource, the xaml page etc.

Comment: @Csharpest my bad,added some code

Comment: Just some ideas: Does the problem only occur with FontSize="Micro"? Maybe you have Custom Renderers for your Label on Android that cause the problem?

Comment: @user2074945 nope, even with the default "welcome to xamarin forms" content page it still removes the white spaces

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, i have found the problem

it was a Icon file created with Icomon and FontAwesome that was force removing the spaces, removing the file fixed everything